# Event.target.value not returning the expected value

Tags: javascript, input, event-handling, dom-events

My code is working but I'm curious to know why... I think it has something to do with the reference in memory but I can't find a direct answer.

Some context, I had to modify the value of a phone field on each input to trim the spaces between the strings.

```js
const phoneInput = document.querySelector('.phoneInput')
phoneInput.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
  const trimedValue = event.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '')
  return event.target.value = trimedValue
})
```

This is done and works.

My question is, why isn't it working when I write this ?

```js
const phoneInput = document.querySelector('.phoneInput')
phoneInput.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
  return event.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '')
})
```

Comment: Because `.replace` function returns a new, updated copy of the string rather than changing the string in place. Note: Returning a value from within your input event handler function doesn't do anything.

Comment: since strings are immutable in javascript, there's no string method that mutates the string itself, string methods return a new string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply because you're assigning some value to event.target.value in your first block but in your second block you're just getting the value from event.target.value and performing some operation on it.